# Rspec fails with "no route match" for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

I'm trying to test my controllers that are accessed via nested routes but I keep getting errors say "No routes matches.

#### spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

module V1
  module Forms
    RSpec.describe SectionsController, type: :controller do
      before(:all) do
        attributes = attributes_for(:form)
        @form = Form.make(attributes)
      end

      context 'CRUD' do
        it 'create' do
          post :create, json_api_format { attributes_for(:section) }, form_id: @form[:id]
          expect(response).to be_successful
          expect(json_data).to include(:type, :attributes)
        end

        it 'update' do
          section = create(:section)
          patch :update, id: section[:id], form_id: @form[:id], data: attributes_for(:section, title: 'New Title')
          expect(response.status).to eq(200)
          expect(json_data).to include(:id, :type, :attributes)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
resources :forms, only: [:index, :create, :update, :show] do
  resources :sections, only: [:create, :update] do
    resources :element, only: [:create, :update]
  end
end
```

#### sections_controller.rb

```
module V1
  module Forms
    class SectionsController < ApiController
      def create
        form = Form.find(form_id)
        section = form.sections.create(section_params)
        render json: section, include: '*', status: :created
      end

      def update
        form = Form.find(form_id)
        section = form.sections.find(section_id)
        section.update(section_params)
        render json: section, include: '*', status: :ok
      end

      private

      def section_params
        ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params, only: %i(form_id, title, step))
      end

      def form_id
        params[:form_id]
      end

      def section_id
        params[:id]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### spec/support/json.rb

```
def json_data
  data = JSON.parse(response.body)['data']
  case data
  when Array
    data
  else
    data.with_indifferent_access
  end
end

def json_api_format(id = nil)
  case id
  when Hash
    { id.keys.first => id.values.first.id, data: { attributes: yield.delete_if { |key, _| key == 'id' } } }
  when Integer
    { id: id, data: { attributes: yield.delete_if { |key, _| key == 'id' } } }
  else
    { data: { attributes: yield } }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is usually because the arguments to `post/patch` are wrong. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers. Make sure you are really passing a single hash (if that is what you intend).

Comment: Why are you yielding to a block that does nothing but run a method to build a hash? Couldn't you just pass the appropriate Hash instead?

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm not sure, that code is not my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your routes don't represent the 2 modules you're trying to use (V1 and Forms), you need to enclose these routes in namespaces, like:

```
namespace :V1 do
  namespace :forms do
    resources :sections, only: [:create, :update] do
    resources :element, only: [:create, :update]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo in your `update` action of your `sections_controller.rb`. Your method is named `updated` rather than `update`.

Comment: Good catch. The problem however still persists.